# Dapper fluent map doesn't change name of my column

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-fluentmap

I have installed Dapper extension + fluentmapper for customing my own columns.
I have followed examples but nothing, the name of my column doesn't change.

I'm doing repository.

Models :

```
public class AppareilsReparations
    {
        public string reference_aff { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapper :

```
public class AppareilsReparationsMapper: EntityMap<AppareilsReparations>
    {
        public AppareilsReparationsMapper()
        {
            Map(p => p.reference_aff).ToColumn("Num_dossier");
        }
    }
```

AppareilsReparationsRepository.cs :

```
public AppareilsReparations GetSingleAppareilsReparationsByRef(string ref_sav)
        {
            try
            {      
               // List<Droits> droit_utilisateur = GetDroits("admin");              
                return db.Query<AppareilsReparations>
                       ("select reference_aff from v_appareils_reparations where ref_sav_client =@ref_sav", new { ref_sav }).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            catch (SqlException sql)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sql.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

AppareilsReparationsController.cs :

```
public AppareilsReparations GetSingleAppareilsReparations(string ref_sav)
        {
            return _arp.GetSingleAppareilsReparationsByRef(ref_sav);
        }
```

And i have initialized in my Global.asax

```
   FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.AddMap(new Mapper.AppareilsReparationsMapper());
            });
```

Comment: While running with a debugger can you inspect `FluentMapper.EntityMaps` in the line before calling `db.Query`?

Comment: hi in dapper.fluentmap.mapping.propertyMap : columnName "num_dossier"

Answer (score 0):

someone have an idea about my problem ?